# How to derive dependently typed eliminators?

Tags: reference-request, recursion, type-theory, dependent-types, inductive-datatypes

In dependently-typed programming, there are two main ways of decomposing data and performing recursion:

- **Dependent pattern matching**: function definitions are given as multiple clauses. Unification ensures that all omitted cases are impossible, and an external solver ensures that recursion is well-founded.
- **Eliminators**: Each inductive datatype $D$ has an associated constant $E_D$, which acts as an induction principle, and as recursive function that decomposes values of type $D$. These are more verbose, but have the advantage of being total (all cases are covered by $E_D$) and terminating by construction.

I've seen eliminators for common datatypes, like $Nat$, where the eliminator is basically mathematical induction, or $List$, where the eliminator is basically a fold.

I've been reading several papers on dependent pattern matching, and many refer to type theories in which datatypes can be defined, and eliminators are provided by the theory. For example, [Eliminating Dependent Pattern Matching](http://cs.ru.nl/~james/RESEARCH/goguen2006.pdf) describes how UTT is based on eliminators, and how pattern matching can be converted to elimination in the presence of axiom $K$. My understanding is that, once a datatype is defined, the theory provides the eliminator.

What I haven't found (or at least, haven't recognized if I've seen it) is a good description of how one can derive the eliminators, both their types and their semantics.

Can someone point me to a reference that describes how one can obtain an eliminator from the definition of a datatype?

Comment: I'm sure there's a description in the calculus of constructions or Coq literature (for strictly positive types — Coq's eliminators on more complex types aren't fully general).

Comment: @Gilles My understanding was that Coq didn't use eliminators, but instead uses separate match and (guarded) fix operators.

Comment: The core language doesn't use eliminators, but when you define a type, Coq generates an eliminator which is defined in terms of `fix` and `match`. I don't have a reference at hand, but I know I've read something about how this eliminator is generated. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/104/recursive-definitions-over-an-inductive-type-with-nested-components may be of interest.

Comment: For any inductive type `T`, Coq defines an induction principle `T_ind` which is a dependent eliminator. This is defined in terms of recursion and pattern matching, but you could in principle assume it as a new constant having the same type (with the same semantics).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The canonical reference for this is Peter Dybjer, *[Inductive Families](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~peterd/papers/Inductive_Families.pdf)*, which gives a pretty comprehensive treatment of inductive families based on eliminators.

Answer (score 6):

You might find some of our recent [papers](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers.html) on this useful, as we derive eliminators for lambda-encoded datatypes.  For example, see this [one](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/cpp-2018.pdf) for generic derivation of eliminators, and this [one](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~astump/papers/from-realizability-to-induction-aaron-stump.pdf) for the basic technique applied just to the Nat type.